# Unable to implement Singalr notifications to existing MVC project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I tried to implement Signalr notification to my existing MVC project and my code in the View as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <span class="noti glyphicon glyphicon-bell"><span class="count">&nbsp;</span></span>
                <div class="noti-content">
                    <div class="noti-top-arrow"></div>
                    <ul id="notiContent"></ul>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @* Add Jquery Library *@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @* Add css  *@
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /*Added css for design notification area, you can design by your self*/
        /* COPY css content from youtube video description*/

    </style>

    @* Add jquery code for Get Notification & setup signalr *@
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Click on notification icon for show notification
            $('span.noti').click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $('.noti-content').show();
                var count = 0;
                count = parseInt($('span.count').html()) || 0;
                //only load notification if not already loaded
                if (count > 0) {
                    updateNotification();
                }
                $('span.count', this).html('&nbsp;');
            })
            // hide notifications
            $('html').click(function () {
                $('.noti-content').hide();
            })
            // update notification
            function updateNotification() {
                $('#notiContent').empty();
                $('#notiContent').append($('<li>Loading...</li>'));

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/home/GetNotificationContacts',
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#notiContent').empty();
                        if (response.length  == 0) {
                            $('#notiContent').append($('<li>No data available</li>'));
                        }
                        $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                            $('#notiContent').append($('<li>New contact : ' + value.ContactName + ' (' + value.ContactNo + ') added</li>'));
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                })
            }
            // update notification count
            function updateNotificationCount() {
                var count = 0;
                count = parseInt($('span.count').html()) || 0;
                count++;
                $('span.count').html(count);
            }
            // signalr js code for start hub and send receive notification
            var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;


            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log('Notification hub started');
            });

            //signalr method for push server message to client
            notificationHub.client.notify = function (message) {
                if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {
                    updateNotificationCount();
                }
            }

        })
    </script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

---

In the Line

```
// signalr js code for start hub and send receive notification
            var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;


            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log('Notification hub started');
            });
```

$.connection does not have a definition

and When running the application

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notificationHub' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Login:219)
    at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
```

It shows the error line as
 var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;

But when I tried to implement in a new project it worked after removing some additional scripts references, but in this project it did not worked

Here is the example I followed 
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/05/push-notification-system-with-signalr.html

This works fine for empty MVC project but when trying to implement the same to existing one gives this issue.

// signalr js code for start hub and send receive notification var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;

$.connection does not have a definition which should come from jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js

Any idea to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

i'm also developing a project with signalr and i guess also that this is a referencing problem.

Look at your code again, the line:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

and the line:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Here you are referencing your jQuery libraries 2 times. I would refactor the referencing and keep it only in one place and before the signalr code. Because signalr depends on jquery library. I suggest you to go with this hierarchy:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryTables")
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Hope it helps. Let me know it you have any question!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I tried it but still having the same problem. Here is the example I followed http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/05/push-notification-system-with-signalr.html. This works fine for empty MVC project but when trying to implement the same to existing one gives this issue. // signalr js code for start hub and send receive notification
            var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
$.connection does not have a definition

Comment: are you still using <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>? I think the problem is here. Let me look again after it and update you if i find something new

Comment: The problem could be also with the bundles that you have at the end of you code: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap"). Have you tried to remove them? You need also to make sure that the order is like this: <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.js"></script>

<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script> and make your hub class as public, like this: public class ChatHub : Hub

Comment: and very important, add this annotation to your Hub Class: [HubName("notificationHub")]. Like this: [HubName("notificationHub")]
    public class NotificationHub : Hub

Comment: I removed All of them. Did the change you mentioned and the only script tags remaining in my page now are  
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @* Add css  *@
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: also for the class, NotificationHub : Hub? Did it work?

Comment: Yes , Added but still have the same problem, I have a working solution which wad developed using an empty mvc application. in there when I press $. then connection comes from the drop down but in this existing mvc application that does not come and I think the script is not linked with signalr js files. Any idea that you have Sir.

Comment: do you have these filesin your project? <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script> <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"> - is there any other error in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, All these files are in the project and no errors in the browser console.

Comment: Dear  alaa_sayegh, Thanks a lot for your help, finally got it corrected by following your guidelines. That was very helpful. Thanks a lot again Sir

Comment: ok thats great news, good work dude!! than you can mark it as an answer and vote me up :)